# CMake copy file only if Debug or RelWithDebInfo build

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(NBody LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

add_executable(NBody 
    main.cpp
)

add_library(OpenCL SHARED IMPORTED)
if(WIN32)
    set_property(TARGET OpenCL PROPERTY IMPORTED_IMPLIB_DEBUG "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/Windows/Debug/OpenCL.lib")
    set_property(TARGET OpenCL PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/Windows/Debug/OpenCL.dll")
    set_property(TARGET OpenCL PROPERTY IMPORTED_IMPLIB_RELEASE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/Windows/Release/OpenCL.lib")
    set_property(TARGET OpenCL PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/Windows/Release/OpenCL.dll")
    set_property(TARGET OpenCL PROPERTY IMPORTED_IMPLIB_MINSIZEREL "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/Windows/MinSizeRel/OpenCL.lib")
    set_property(TARGET OpenCL PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION_MINSIZEREL "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/Windows/MinSizeRel/OpenCL.dll")
    set_property(TARGET OpenCL PROPERTY IMPORTED_IMPLIB_RELWITHDEBINFO "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/Windows/RelWithDebInfo/OpenCL.lib")
    set_property(TARGET OpenCL PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELWITHDEBINFO "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/Windows/RelWithDebInfo/OpenCL.dll")
endif()

target_link_libraries(NBody PRIVATE
    OpenCL
)

target_compile_definitions(NBody PRIVATE
    CL_HPP_MINIMUM_OPENCL_VERSION=110
    CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION=110
)

if(CMAKE_GENERATOR MATCHES "Visual Studio")
    set(TARGET_BINARY_DIR "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/$<CONFIG>")
else()
    set(TARGET_BINARY_DIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
endif()

add_custom_target(copy_OpenCL ALL)
if(WIN32)
    add_custom_command(
        TARGET copy_OpenCL
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/Windows/$<CONFIG>/OpenCL.dll" ${TARGET_BINARY_DIR}/OpenCL.dll
        BYPRODUCTS ${TARGET_BINARY_DIR}/OpenCL.dll
        VERBATIM
    )
endif()
```

How should I expand `add_custom_command` so that in case if `$<CONFIG>` is *Debug* or *RelWithDebInfo* in **addition** to *OpenCL.dll* also *OpenCL.pdb* gets copied to TARGET_BINARY_DIR ? If *Release* or *MinSizeRel*, **only** *OpenCL.dll* should be copied to TARGET_BINARY_DIR because in those cases *OpenCL.pdb* **does not exist**.

**NOTE:** This CMakeLists.txt file is not yet complete because in addition to `if(WIN32)`, Linux support needs to be added.

Thanks for your help !

**EDIT:**
I have modified `add_custom_command` to

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET copy_OpenCL
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/Windows/$<CONFIG>/OpenCL.dll"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/Windows/$<CONFIG>/OpenCL.pdb>"
        "$<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/Windows/$<CONFIG>/OpenCL.pdb>"
        ${TARGET_BINARY_DIR}/
    BYPRODUCTS ${TARGET_BINARY_DIR}/OpenCL.dll ${TARGET_BINARY_DIR}/OpenCL.pdb
    VERBATIM
)
```

and it work's as I wanted, thank you !

Comment: In the COMMAND's arguments you could use an argument like `$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:/path/to/OpenCL.pdb>`, so it will be expanded to the specified path only in `Debug` build, in other builds the argument will be omitted. Signature for `copy_if_different` CMake command [allows](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-command-line-tool) specification of the multiple files: `copy_if_different <file>... <destination>`. So just make sure that the `<destination>` is not a file but a directory.